# Facebook fanpage Rss encoding error

Tags: php, xml, facebook, character-encoding, rss

This is my fanpage: [https://www.facebook.com/kidsvideo.us](https://www.facebook.com/kidsvideo.us.)

And here is my rss url: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=1433882270183943

There is error encoding when use this rss, I use php simplepie and tried feedburner with the same error: feeds.feedburner.com/KidsVideosFacebookWall

Any solution?

Comment: are you still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is: Facebook use html entity in the xml. Simple use html_entity_decode() to decode the "error content".